# The simplest tabs with history - back button

Tags: jquery, tabs, history

I looking-for the simplest tabs with history back button, but without ajax-loading files/content, like as slide divs.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by tabs having 'history back button', or 'like as slide divs'. Do you want a tab that when clicked, loads the previously loaded page or something?

Comment: Here's a JQuery Plugin to record/get the history : http://plugins.jquery.com/project/historyevent as for a comprehensive tabs/slide-divs... good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe...
How connected http://www.queness.com/resources/html/scroll/horizontal.html with Address jQuery Plugin (http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/)